# Java - Check for byte alignment in byte array search

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code that works for finding a byte[] inside of another byte[]. My question is how can I modify this so that it only finds matches with byte alignment. I'm trying to make something similar to the option in https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/reading.html#find-rfind.

```
public int indexOf(byte[] outerArray, byte[] smallerArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < outerArray.length - smallerArray.length+1; ++i) {
        boolean found = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < smallerArray.length; ++j) {
           if (outerArray[i+j] != smallerArray[j]) {
               found = false;
               break;
           }
        }
        if (found) return i;
     }
   return -1;  
}
```

**Sample from python:**

```
s = ConstBitStream('0x012340001234')
found = s.find('0x1234',bytealigned=False)
(4,)
found2 = s.find('0x1234',bytealigned=True)
(32,)
```

Comment: Please post a sample input and output.

Comment: If I'm understanding the notion of "byte alignment" used in that linked documentation, your code already does only find matches with byte alignment.

Comment: It does not, mine only looks for a matching pattern (all it cares about is a substring basically). It doesn't check if it's in the byte boundaries.

Comment: Define 'byte aligment'. Every byte is aligned on a byte-alignment boundary, by definition.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering the same thing, I want to replicate the results of the python example.

Comment: A bit stream is not a byte array; that is, `0x012340001234` is not `byte[]{0, 1, 2, ...}`; rather, it's like `byte[]{1, 35, 64, 0, 18, 52}`. Did you mean to have an array of hex digits be processed with byte alignment?

Comment: I am using byte[]{1, 35, 64, 0, 18, 52} in my Java code yes, which allows me to find match the other bytes. The problem is figuring out the byte alignment.

Comment: I have data coming in as a byte[] and I am looking for a pattern of bytes that equal to ('0x1234') and are byte aligned.